# Details on applications permissions

Tags: 8.0, store, security

Each application on the marketplace asks for some permissions.
Is there a an existing listing of all these permissions with the associated details ?

For instance, what rights are granted to an application with the `contact` permission ? Can the application have access to all the informations I have on each contact, including the photo, the source and the conversation history ?

I'm not looking for details on the `contact` permission specifically, but for all the possible permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft [explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx) very specifically what each capability allows a developer to do.

> ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS   Provides access to appointment data.
>
> ID_CAP_CONTACTS       Provides access to contacts data.
>
> ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES  Provides access to Xbox LIVE services. This capability must be disclosed because an app could share data with Xbox.
>
> ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE Provides access to device-specific information such as a unique device ID, or the manufacturer or model name.
>
> ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER  Gives an app the ability to use an anonymous Microsoft account to identify the user.
>
> ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA Provides access to the rear (primary) camera or front-facing camera.
>
> ID_CAP_LOCATION   Provides access to location services.
>
> ID_CAP_MAP    Provides access to mapping functionality.
>
> ID_CAP_MEDIALIB   Provides access to the media library.
>
> ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO Provides read-only access to audio items, including lists of audio items and audio item properties such as title and description, in the media library. It also provides the ability to add or delete songs. Delete operations display an additional prompt to the user.
>
> ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO Provides read-only access to photos in the media library, and photo properties, such as category. It also gives an app the ability to save photos in the Camera Roll and Saved Pictures folders.
>
> ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK   Provides read/write access to media items that are currently playing. It also gives an app the ability to add media items to the History, Favorites, and New collections. Also supports background and foreground playback from an app’s isolated storage using theMediaElement control.
>
> ID_CAP_MICROPHONE Provides access to the phone’s microphone. An app with this capability can record without a visual indication that the microphone is recording.
>
> ID_CAP_NETWORKING Provides access to network services. This capability must be disclosed because an app could incur charges when a phone is roaming.
>
> ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER    Provides the ability to use thePhoneCallTask API.
>
> ID_CAP_PROXIMITY  Provides access to Near Field Communication (NFC) services.
>
> ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION  Provides the ability to receive push notifications from an internet service. This capability must be disclosed because an app could incur roaming charges.
>
> ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE  Provides access to data storage on an external storage component, such as an SD card.
>
> ID_CAP_RINGTONE_ADD   Provides the ability to add ringtones to the phone.
>
> ID_CAP_SENSORS    Provides access to any Windows Phone sensor.
>
> ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION Provides access to speech recognition and text-to-speech (TTS) services.
>
> ID_CAP_VOIP   Provides access to voice over IP (VoIP) calling services.
>
> ID_CAP_WALLET Provides access to interactions with Wallet such as saving, updating, and deleting deals, membership cards, and payment instruments.
>
> ID_CAP_WALLET_SECUREELEMENT   Provides access to a Wallet secure element for secure NFC transactions.
>
> ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT    Provides access to a web browser component. This capability must be disclosed because an app could use scripting, which introduces security risks.
>
> ID_HW_FRONTCAMERA Indicates that your app has some features that require the front-facing camera. It is used only to warn users that don’t have a front-facing camera on their phone.